# How do I introduce entropy to an encoded Base64 string?

Tags: c#, web-services, cryptography, aes, entropy

I'm creating a json webservice (C#, WCF) and I need to identify a user. There is no session management, therefore the user would need to send an identifying string for every command. The solution I came up with is to AES Encrypt the user's credentials and the time when the string would 'expire' (currently 1000ms), then use Base64 to encode it (HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode) before sending (via URL or otherwise).

My problem is this: The encoded string almost always looks the same, with very few changes (I assume that would be the Minutes & Seconds of the expiry, since the credentials date and hour very rarely changes. Although a string can only be used once (the last received string is recorded, and the second to the last is likely to have expired), I still think it would be easy to just intercept and block the GET request, fudge a few things then resend it. And when the attack is automated, even the timeout probably wouldn't work.

So. How can I introduce additional (reversible) entropy to an AES encoded Base64 string?

Comment: Why does it need to be reversible? Can't you just generate GUID, save it to the database along with other information you need (user, timestamp) and send it to the user?

Answer (score 3):

A better way to do this is to have a server side session which holds the information. The cookie on the client side would be a GUID of sorts which is temporarily authenticated. On the server side it would correlate with their username. This can expire on the server side as well in order to prevent it from being reused down the road.

This would allow for the user to be authenticated with a random string, without having to constantly transmit their username and password. With Rainbow tables, it's very easy to reverse hashed passwords and other things.

Adding a SALT to the encrypted string before encrypting will help as well. I would recommend that you add at least 15 extra random characters to the end. This will make brute forcing a lot more difficult in the event you choose to go that route.

Comment: I believe it's not very easy to reverse hashed passwords, even with rainbow tables, if you correctly use salt.

Comment: @svick that depends on the strength of the passwords, password strenght in offline scenarios is a serious security issue in general, computers are just too fast

Answer (score 1):

The way to add entropy to an AES/CBC encrypted data is to use a random IV, and prepend that IV (of exactly 16 bytes, the size of an AES block) to the ciphertext, then base 64 encode it. I hope you are using CBC over ECB as it might be insecure.